# Filter sub array object

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the data in a `FlatList` of `react-native`,

I have several filters,

The first is easy a word, the second filter (independent of the previous one) a list (array) of tags.

**The data**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "ID": 1,
    "name": "Name 1",
    "tags": Array [
      Object {
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "tag 1",
      },
      Object {
        "ID": 2,
        "name": "tag 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "ID": 2,
    "name": "Name 2",
    "tags": Array [
      Object {
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "tag 1",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

**The React Native component**

`searchedText = "string"` *works well* & `selectedTags = []` *like key `tags` described above*

```
<FlatList
  data={ 
    filterType === null ? items
      : filterType === "text" ? items.filter(item => item.name.includes(searchedText))
      : filterType === "tags" ? items.filter(item => item.tags.includes(selectedTags))
      : null
  }
  keyExtractor={( item ) => item.ID.toString() }
  renderItem={ ({ item }) => <AnotherComponent item={ item }/> }
/>
```

I do not know how to work deeply, Do you have a solution to filter the selected tag(s)?

Like :

```
items.filter(item => item.tags.includes([{name:"tag1"},{name:"tag2"}]))
```

Comment: This article can help you. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699

Comment: Thank you for this paper, but it does not help me, I do filter give them but I do not know how to do it deep `Array > Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
items.filter(item => item.tags
  .some(tag => selectedTags
    .map(selectedTag => selectedTag.name)
    .includes(tag.name)));
```